# why show this error message "Main.js: Unexpected token "

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

import React from 'react'
import HornedBeast from './HornedBeast'
import './Main.css'
export class Main extends React.Component {

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Main Page</h1>  
        
        imageArr.map((item,index)=>{
        return(
            <HornedBeast
                key={index}
                imgUrl={item.image_url}
                title={item.title}
                description={item.description}
            />
            )

        })


        </div>
    )
}
```

}

export default Main

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your javaScript inside the JSX in `{ ... }`

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

export default class Main extends React.Component {
  imageArr = [];

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Main Page</h1>
        {this.imageArr.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <HornedBeast
              key={index}
              imgUrl={item.image_url}
              title={item.title}
              description={item.description}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function HornedBeast() {
  return <div></div>;
}
```

Comment: he give me this
 Unexpected token (41:4)

  39 |                 <h1>Main Page</h1>  
  40 |                 render() {
> 41 |     return (
     |     ^
  42 |         <div>
  43 |             <h1>Main Page</h1>  
  44 |             {

Comment: I edited my answer. This code works in https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: i will try it very soon , and many thanks for help me